# Listen for EOF for deleted fifo / named pipe

Tags: bash, shell, named-pipes, eof, fifo

I created this fifo / named pipe"

```
my_named_pipe="$HOME/foobar"
mkfifo "$my_named_pipe"

while read line; do on_fifo_msg "$line"; done < ${my_named_pipe} &
```

at some point later on, I delete this fifo from the filesystem - I assume the read loop ends because of EOF or whatever - but how can I listen for that event? How can I listen for when that read loop ends?

Comment: I guess I could use `wait;`or perhaps I could use `trap foo SIGCHLD`...but is there another way?

Comment: Deleting the FIFO won't cause EOF. You only get that when the writer closes their end.

Comment: There's no event caused by deleting the FIFO.

Comment: hmm ok how do I close the fifo from the writer's end?

Comment: When the writer exits, that will normally closeit.

Comment: Well there's potentially more than one writer, I don't really see how that works, I just write to it from other processes with `echo "foo" > fifo`

Comment: That command will open the FIFO, write the message, and then close it. The loop should end when that happens, without giving any other processes a chance to write to it.

Comment: ahh I see, you must be right, because that's the behavior I have been witnessing...so you can only echo to a fifo once??

Comment: If you want to keep it open, you can run a background process that's redirected to the FIFO and goes to sleep for a long time. The reader gets EOF when all writing processes close it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there's any way for the `while read` loop to detect the FIFO being deleted automatically.

You could use another loop to periodically check whether the FIFO still exists, and kill the read loop:

```
while read line; do on_fifo_msg "$line"; done < ${my_named_pipe} &
read_pid=$!
while kill -0 $read_pid; do
    if ! [[ -e "$my_named_pipe" ]];
    then kill $read_pid
    fi
    sleep 1
done &
```

`kill -0 $read_pid` tests that the read loop process still exists.